# Unable to login to wso2 carbon

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I was configuring wso2 to user mysql db as primary source in deployment.toml file. service are running without any error. when i try to access carbon console i'm getting error in logs.

Error:-
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Operation is not supported

Please help me resolving
Thanks,
prudhvi

Comment: Is it possible to share your deployment.toml file.

Comment: What is the product & version you are trying to use?

Comment: issue resolved i disabled the ad user store through carbon console and enabled it's working after that